# Fullcalendar change color of some events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to change color of some events in Fullcalendar plugin.

I tried "className" property in the constructor of "events" object. However, i couldnt achieve to change the color and css. I checked on the firebug. The css of the event td's are still using default css.

I am generating calendar in the codebehind by using RegisterClientScriptBlock. Maybe that can be a problem, but i dont think so.  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For class Name '**other**' I've gotten the following **CSS** to work. At first, I was missing one of the selectors and had the same issue as you.

```
.other, .fc-agenda .other .fc-event-time, .other a {
    background-color: #066333;/* background color */
    border-color: #066333;/* border color (often same as background-color) */
    color: #fff;/* text color */
}
```

Comment: yep. i created a bunch of new css classes for that issue. Only changing the color wasnt enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've accoumplished this before using jQuery's addClass like `$("."+calEvent.id).addClass("classWithDifferentCSS");`  Each cal event has a class with its ID.